How to obtain byte array from request body in Nest.JS with Express?
I'm trying to hash the byte array of the body of my POST request to compare the hash value with the one similarly hashed by the client on their side. My issue is that I cannot retrieve the byte array. I am using Nest.JS along with express. Below is the code I'm attempting to use. However, it doesn't work as the 'end' event is never triggered.
Please share your thoughts on how I might accomplish this task
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class VerifyHashMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const contentHash = req.headers['sum'];

    const chunks: Buffer[] = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
      const rawBody = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      const hash = this.createHash(rawBody);

      if (contentHash !== hash) {
        res.status(400).send('Hash mismatch');
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  }
}

